# How to see Windows Version with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, version

I am making a python program which would act as windows cmd, but I need a code which will display Windows's version. [Highlighted one]

[image: Hint]

How to make it?

Comment: It must display '10.0.10586' only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys

ver = sys.getwindowsversion()
print("{}.{}.{}".format(ver.major, ver.minor, ver.build))
```

Output :
`10.0.18362`

Comment: Good work! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

```
import platform
platform.version()
```

My output was '10.0.17134'

Comment: I displays `Windows-10-10.0.10586-SP0`, not `10.0.10586`!

Comment: Otherwise good.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import os
os.system('ver')
```

Comment: I displays just like Command Prompt's first line of banner: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]`. But nice work!